# Oracle date comparison query doesn't execute as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I had the below condition in my query:

```
AND support_version_valid_from_dt >= to_date(to_char(
    support_version_valid_from_dt, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS'))
```

And I got the error: [Error] Execution (18: 17): ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
So I tried this. But this doesnt work. I don't understand the date parsing oracle has. Especially for comparing dates. Can someone help me understand the key gotcha's for how query date comparison in oracle works?

```
select  to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS'))
 from dual
```

Comment: Why are you converting a `date` to a string using `to_char()` and then back to a `date` using `to_date()`? That does not make sense. You are essentially writing `where support_version_valid_from_dt > support_version_valid_from_dt` which will never be true.

Comment: What is the type of the column and what are you trying to do?  It is hard to figure out your intention from the non-working code.

Comment: There will be a character variable coming in, that I have to compare with an actual date column

Comment: Look at this:  `WHERE SUPPORT.STORE_SELECTOR = 'R' AND SUPPORTER.STORE_SELECTOR = 'R'
    AND to_char(support_version_valid_from_dt,  'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS') >= to_date('2014/02/11 05:44:31', 'HH:MI:SS')`

Answer (score 1):

`TO_DATE` is the inverse of `TO_CHAR`.  So this should work, if you input a `date` at least:

```
to_date(to_char(input_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS'), 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS')
```

That would convert a `date` to a `char` and back.

Even if it should work, it is not entirely clear why you'd want to do this :)

Comment: because the input date is actually a char that's coming in. and I am comparing dates

Comment: If it;s a `char`, why are you calling `to_char` on it?

Answer (score 0):

You should compare dates to dates, and not store or compare dates as strings.

When you do this:

```
to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS'))
```

... you're doing a conversion of a `DATE` data type to a string using an explicit format model, and then convert that string back to a `DATE` without an explicit format model; so it implicitly uses your session NLS settings. You're effectively doing:

```
to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS'), '<NLS_DATE_FORMAT>')
```

Unless your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` happens to be the same as the explicit model you used, this is likely to error. A common value for that might be `DD-MON-RRRR`, for example; if you plug that into your query you're likely to get the same ORA-01861.

What your actual NLS setting is doesn't really matter. You should never rely on that value, because someone else running your code might have a different setting, so something you've massaged to work for you will still fail for them. (It still surprises me how many people ignore this and assume something that just won't be true in the future).

All of which is somewhat irrelevant. You're converting a date to a string and back to a date, which is largely pointless. Sometimes it's done to drop the time part of a date value, but you're not even doing that here, and you could use `trunc` to achieve that anyway.

In your case, from your comment, instead of this:

```
AND to_char(support_version_valid_from_dt, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS') >=
    to_date('2014/02/11 05:44:31', 'HH:MI:SS')
```

... leave the column value (on the left) as a date:

```
AND support_version_valid_from_dt >=
    to_date('2014/02/11 05:44:31', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

You have to include the whole format model; you had ommitted the actual date part, you can't just pick some of the model (the time in this case). I've also change `HH` to `HH24`; without that you couldn't pass in a time after midday, since you don't have an AM/PM indicator.